# I am trying to deploy MERN app to heroku but getting this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

[enter image description here][1]2022-02-27T16:52:34.545164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
2022-02-27T16:52:34.545165+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-27T16:52:34.545165+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-27T16:52:34.545165+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
2022-02-27T16:52:34.545165+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-02-27T16:52:34.545165+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/routes/auth.js', '/app/index.js' ]
2022-02-27T16:52:34.545166+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-02-27T16:52:34.675107+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-27T16:52:34.918330+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-27T16:52:36.349184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=srs-inotebook.herokuapp.com request_id=0fc9b975-467b-46b0-a78c-cd5811a90519 fwd="157.33.53.30" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Please refer this image:-
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/miAod.png

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add a module to package.json. Might want to double check package.json and all the modules you have used.

Comment: Already included the package json

Comment: It's working fine in localhost, but I'm getting error in deployment

Answer (score 0):

It was solved. It was due to naming conventions. Thanks for your answers !